# Switching regulator not suppressing variance in input?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, switching-regulator

I am having a little problem with my switching regulator, based on a [AP65211A](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP65211A.pdf) and here is my schematic:

[image: schematic diagram]

Parts:

```
Ref Value   Digikey Part#
C6  10uF    1276-6455-1-ND
C7  1000uF  399-6082-ND
R2  100k    RMCF0402JT100KCT-ND
C8  1 uF    1276-1102-1-ND
L1  6.8uH   587-3143-1-ND
R3  75k     RMCF0402JT75K0CT-ND
R4  78.7k   RC0402FR-0778K7L
R5  14.7k   YAG2984CT-ND
C9  22uF    1276-6780-1-ND
C10 220uF   490-13970-1-ND
C11 470uF   P5141-ND
```

It actually works great overall when plugged into a decent bench PSU and can deliver 2 amps to a test load, without the voltage dropping out at all.

**The problem is when it is connected to almost any 12V wall adapter, with any voltage ripple.**

Here is the best wall adapter I have been able to find (after buying many trying to find the most stable one). This is the input (12V) and output (5V) when hooked up to my switching supply, under no load:

[image]

[image]

Then with a 5 ohm load:

[image]

Added more and more capacitance to the input or output doesn't seem to affect it. Any ideas?

Right now, I do not feel comfortable connecting this to a microcontroller or anything, because the voltage spikes would definitely fry them.

Thanks.

---

Edit: Here is my KiCad Project, the entire project will be open sourced at some point. It is a controller for a saltwater fish tank: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n5knjkvoevhnout/ATO_CHANGE_CONTROLLER_V3.7z?dl=0

Edit: Here is another image using the math function to create a differential measurement:

[image]

They all match perfectly with the input supply (even when not connected to my switching circuit).

If I power the 12V rail from a bench power supply (Circuit Test PSA-2530D) this is what I get:

No Load:
[image]

Loaded:
[image]

Comment: It certainly doesn't match the datasheet's transient response.  Can you post a picture of your layout?  Does a step change in input voltage *eventually* settle out at the output?

Comment: Is your adapter grounded or floating output? Is that a "real" oscilloscope or some kind of USB thing?

Comment: @TimWescott I will edit and add most of my PCB layout

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I am capturing using an Analog Discovery, but it turns shows the same on a "real" oscilloscope, this is just much easier to capture to post here.  The Negative on the output of all of the adapters I have checked is directly shorted to ground.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany if I have an O-scope from Agilent or Tek that has a full featured front panel *and* a USB interface is it a real O-scope or a "USB thing"?  And if the front panel dies but I can still use it over the USB interface, is in a real O-scope or a "USB thing?"

Comment: So you have at a minimum a ground loop between the oscilloscope ground and the adapter ground.  Can you use differential probes to measure the output? (connect the scope ground to the circuit ground directly or through a 50 ohm  resistor and put one probe on + out and one on - out.

Comment: @TimWescott I think you know what I'm getting at- the sample rates look pretty slow and with that sweep rate there could be aliasing going on. I have a lot of doubts what we're seeing is both real and representative of what happens with the scope or whatever disconnected. And even my Tek scope has no anti-aliasing filter so setting the sweep rate too low, even with the alleged 2Gs/s sample rate  leads to a lot of lies being displayed  on the screen. I guess they just discard samples to do the decimation.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I can go get my Tektronix from the lab in the next few days to check with it. 

And yes my USB scope is measuring a differential between the common ground and the 5V rail and 12V rail. I will post some more images using the USB scope in a min here

Comment: Do you understand the difference between using two probes vs. using one probe and a ground clip?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Since the ground is common everywhere I was measuring I didn't think using two probes or just one would matter I have posted an image of the 5V signal both from channel 1 and a second channel that is generated by subtracting channel 2(GND) from channel 1

Comment: The source impedance ratio is too high =  Zs/Load  and C11/C7=2

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I can add more capacitance to the input or output, how much more should I try?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I added 4400uF to both the input and output, at different times and the waveforms remained the same after stabilizing.

Comment: WHat was the ESR of the Cap compared to a 5 Ohm load?  When you understand the impedance ratios , you will see why the  source impedance cause Line regulation error.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Unfortunately I can not find an ESR rating for the large electrolytes I am using, but the ceramics are supposed to be small, I have updated the above post with a sample when using a bench supply to power the 12V rail... if it operates fine with a bench supply could it still be the ESR?

Comment: If your reference design calls for a low ESR 10uF cap, don't assume it is, especially if it has no specs., I believe It should be 10 mohm max ESR and prefer. much lower to have a good impedance ratio with L at 500Khz for line regulation error.  These are  your problems with specs and understanding impedance ratios...  with Xc(f) and ESR  similarily XL(f) + DCR ( which is OK here)

Comment: Even though it works fine with a bench supply? I will find lower ESR caps if you think this is the only problem. @SunnyskyguyEE75

Comment: I want you to think if this makes sense.  \$ΔVin = I*(dt/C + ESR) \$  from Ic=CdV/dt and V=I*ESR  where I is controlled by the load and regulator and dt=1us @ 50% duty cycle.  Then estimate  unregulated supply impedance and how that affects the average input from your measurements.  Then calculate the results.

Comment: I ended up taking the project to the lab, this is more or less a "fun" project and didn't want to take it to work. But it definitely is something to do with my scope at home, the other real scops showed no issues and actually nearly perfect operation.